# How to encrypt my web application on a Linux server

Tags: linux, security, encryption

My company wants to make private deployment for our web application on a LAN network for a client. I want them to have access to the database since it is all their data, but I do not want them to have access to the code since it has our companies propriety and access tokens for various accounts. It would be easy to limit their access if it was on a far away server, but since they have the physical machine I am worried they could hack the hard disk.

Is there a way to encrypt my application yet still make it run normally when in operation? If yes how and what are the tools to do this? I am using Rails and Apache Passenger if it matters.

Comment: You'd have to run a native/bytecode compiled version of your sensitive source code and delete source from the machine you give your client. Not familiar with ruby on rails so don't know if possible. Also if you use your sensitive passwords do so through encrypted connections so that they can't be intercepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a byte code compiler.  A good example is [Ruby Encoder](http://rubyencoder.com/)